# Envio de form com anexo - Javascript

Tags: javascript, email

Bom dia a todos, 
estou desenvolvendo um sistema de envio de e-mail, extremamente simples utilizando o javascript (**Jquery**).

No momento já consigo enviar o e-mail utilizando o smtpjs.
a primeira parte do meu sistema esta Ok.

Porem eu gostaria de anexar no e-mail algumas planilhas em Excel, eu já tentei alguns procedimentos e não consegui.

Segue código atual:

```
$('#enviar').on('click',function(e){
e.preventDefault()
    var email = $('#email').val()
    var titulo =$('#titulo').val()
    var corpo =$('#corpo').val()

    Email.send({
        To : email,
        From : "teste@hotmail.com",
        Subject : titulo,
        Body :corpo
    }).then(message => alert(message))

})


<div class="row">
            <form class="col-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" aria-describedby="Digite o email de destino">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="titulo">Titulo do Email</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="titulo">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="corpo">Corpo do email</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="corpo" rows="3"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inp">Enviar Arquivo</label>
                    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="input">
                </div>
                <button id="enviar" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

O cara respondeu a pergunta, porem apagou a resposta, bom essa é a resposta que ele tinha postado e deu certo, fico grato!

```
function uploadFileToServer()
{
   var file = event.srcElement.files[0];
   console.log(event.srcElement)
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
   reader.onload = function () {
       var dataUri = "data:" + file.type + ";base64," + btoa(reader.result);
       Email.send({
           SecureToken :"",
           To : "",
           From :"",
           Subject : "Send with base64 attachment",
           Body : "Sending file:" + file.name,
           Attachments : [
            {
                name : file.name,
                data : dataUri
            }]
       }).then(
         message => alert(message)
       );
   };
   reader.onerror = function() {
       console.log('Erro!');
   };
}
```

Comment: Mas é bom explicar o que foi feito porque pode ajudar alguém no futuro, e não colocar apenas o código.